# How can we kill the deerclops in don't starve together?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Playing with the two of us, we have reached the point where we can likely survive through winter, at last. But the deerclops totally -wrecks- us.

It's also incredibly frustrating to then have to replay hours of work to instantly die again.

We tried creating many log suits and the ham bat and doing a beatdown on it but we lost too much hp and insanity and we had no way to know how injured it was.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you finally manage to deal with the Deerclops?

Comment: Nope, it put us off going back to the game because it's quite a grind to get through winter, and after all that effort to get rekt in a couple of minutes just makes it frustrating. We tried once I think, and it felt like we did massive damage but still died. I think it's a real oversight of the game to suddenly ramp the difficulty up to insane highs and give you one shot to figure out how to beat it, and if you fail making you replay the entire game up to that point.

Comment: Remember that if you're hosting your own game on your computer, the host can rollback to the last save whenever something goes wrong. All you have to do is type the "/rollback" command in the chat. The last save is: either the last time you survived for an entire day, or the last time the host logged out and turned off the server.

Comment: Does that work in multiplayer?

Comment: Yeah, I do it all the time with my friend when a hazardous fire has started in our camp and I'm the one hosting.

Comment: Cool, might give that a go then if we play again

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the best ways to kill him is to lead him into a large Beefalo herd, preferably in heat. Lead him into a swamp full of tentacles. Or just plane old kiting with a spike bat (tentacle drop). I've also seen people using Gunpowder. Lastly, if you have enough stingers, make a huge filed of spike traps and lead him into it while kiting.

Comment: Hmm, we found that he just wrecks everything we kited him into. We tanked him for a bit with the hambat, and blasted him with the fire staff, kited him through tree monsters, pigs, spiders, and the spider queen, and he was still alive and then he killed us and smashed up our base. Maybe tentacles are better

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds about right. He has a ridiculous amount of health. The #1 trick for us has been large Beefalo herd(s) in heat. I'm talking 20-30 Beefalo. Then you end up with a motherload of drops and it also thins out the herd (as they can get quite hazardous when they get too large).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I play as Wigfrid in a server alone, before fighting any season giant, I make sure:

- I can deal enough damage to kill them (at least 4000 damages in the case of the Deerclops) with my equipped weapon. For the Deerclops, that's around 38% of a Battle Spear durability as Wigfrid; it would take around 79% of a regular Spear to take him down with characters who have normal damage multiplier.
- I have 2 or 3 helms available in my inventory, just in case (or anything that gives at least 80% damage protection).
- I have at least 75% of my character's health (assuming you're not playing as Maxwell, since his health cap only at 75).
- I have some healing items (preferably Healing Salve), just in case.

Once I'm ready, I just rush in and attack.

During the fight:

- When you just started the fight, the Deerclops needs to hit you 3 times to freeze you. But if you already got frozen and he unfroze you by hitting you, the next 2 hit will freeze you.
- Everytime the Deerclops hit you, you'll notice your character will get a "pale" tone, which means they're "freezing". Upon being hit twice, run away until the pale colour fades away before charging again, this way the next hit you take won't freeze you.
- If you're playing with a friend, your friend should be standing on the opposite side of the Deerclops, this way you don't both get hit when he attacks.
- Keep hitting him until he's dead.

As I pointed out in the comments, if either of you is hosting the game (rather than playing in a public dedicated server), whenever something goes wrong during the fight, the host can type `/rollback` in the chat and press enter.

This will allow you to start the game over from the last save (usually the last morning save, or the last time the host disconnected the server), instead of replaying the entire game again whenever you fail and/or die.

---

Another solution if you intend to fight is to have some Treeguards (not just one) to help you in your fight.

A Treeguard is a tree monster that have a chance at spawning if you cut too many (Lumpy) Evergreen trees. They come in 3 sizes, and their stats (damage, walking speed, attack range, health) scales proportionally with their size:

- Short (they spawn from the tiniest trees, scale is 0.7)
- Medium (they spawn from the medium sized trees and look like adult tree, scale is 1)
- Tall (they spawn from the adult trees and look gigantic, scale is 1.2)

Between the beginning of the game and Winter, you have 21 days, and the Deerclops usually spawn around the 30th day, which mean you have around that much time to cut as many trees as you can to spawn Treeguards. Cutting adult Evergreen will allow you to retrieve 2 pine cones to plant 2 more trees. Repeat the cycle to have more trees to cut.

Whenever you spawn a Treeguard, don't kill him. Instead, lead him far away enough then start planting pine cones until the Treeguard forgets you and plants himself in the ground. Then return cutting trees to keep spawning more treeguards. The more you have the better.

Once the Deerclops attack, if possible, try to make it so the Treeguards are sandwiching the Deerclops (at least one out front and one in the back), this way he can't freeze them both, and one of them is still attacking him.

Upon doing this, 2 medium-sized Treeguards I had spawned, managed to kill the Deerclops "on their own"*, and they both survived.

*: I initially attempted to kill the Deerclops myself, but I had to deal with some shadows (because I had 0 sanity). Luckily for me, when the Deerclops chased me, he broke a tree, which triggered the Treeguards into attacking him. In the end, I barely attacked the Deerclops. So, in a way, the 2 Treeguards sandwiching the Deerclops managed to kill him alone.

---

If fighting isn't a solution, when I hear a "warning sound" from the giants, I run as far as I can from my camp (if I have one).

Once the giant monster has spawned, I leave him on that part of the map (e.g. a new Bearger won't spawn in the next Winter, if the previous one wasn't killed). You just have to make sure that nobody approach that part of the map (consider it a quarantine area), so he won't notice you nor your buildings.

Although doing that would prevent the Bearger from respawning, I heard the Deerclops despawns after Winter, so he would respawn on subsequent Winter anyway.

Comment: I thought the deerclops would just move to your base from anywhere, or at least, follow you back to your base if you try to run away

Comment: The Deerclops is attracted to structures (he likes destroying them). But if you're too far away from your base, once he spawns, he'll just wander around aimlessly. As long as you don't approach him too much, he won't bother you. Just make sure you don't leave him in an important area though (e.g. somewhere empty, without any important resources).